# Ridiculous input width in Firefox

Tags: html, firefox, cross-browser

When I have an `input` field with a `size` attribute, it seems to be wider in Firefox compared to Chromium.

The issue gets A LOT worse when a language such as `zh-HK` is set (either through the html `lang` attribute or the `Content-Language` header). In this case, the `input` seems to be at least twice as wide in Firefox.

What is the reason for this huge discrepancy?

Please check the snippet below in different browsers:

```html
<html lang="zh-HK">
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/kQUUnVF.png"><br>
<input size="50">
```

This is what it looks like for me in Firefox:

[image: screenshot]

And yes, I know I can set the width using CSS.

Comment: That might depend on what font is used, and all the properties that influence it (font-family, font-size, letter-spacing, etc.) – did you normalize those, or are you just letting the browsers use their default values? (Especially for eastern languages, the browsers might use different fonts, if you don’t specify which one is to be used.)

Comment: @CBroe I didn't set any other properties. The computed font-family in Firefox is "Sans". Setting a font on the input element does seem to make a difference.

Comment: I checked Firefox's font settings and the proportional font for HK Chinese is  set to Sans Serif rather than Serif, but changing it doesn't seem to make any difference.

Answer (score 2):

[The specification does not set any standard layout for this property.](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-size-attribute) If you inspect that element with both browser's developer tools, you will find there are different property settings for both. Neither browser is wrong or right.